# Equation to track the change in a definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given the following equations

$$
f(x) = \sqrt{x}\\
\int^x_0f(x)dx
$$

Would it be possible to calculate an equation to calculate the change in the definite integral over x? For example, the change between f(0) and f(2) is 0.667 and 1.219, $f(1) - f(0)$ and $f(2) - f(1)$ respectively. Is there an equation to determine these numbers without utilizing the definite integral for each number from $\int^x_{x-1}f(x)dx$

Answer (score 0):

Well, the rate at which the area under the curve changes is simply the function itself.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Comment: I’m trying to understand this answer, however, I don’t see where the original equation square root of x comes into play.

Comment: @VeeAyeInIn have you heard about the fundamental theorem of calculus as I provided in link?

Comment: I have, I am currently going through it in my Calculus class, although I don’t seem to be learning the material as well as I thought I was.